# Update same values in the field with different values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, update, query

My Table is in the following format in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table11 (id int,col1 float,col2 int);

INSERT INTO table11 (id,col1,col2)
VALUES
(1, 1.1, 1),
(2, 1.2, 1),
(3, 1.3, 1),
(4, 1.4, 1);
```

I want to update the values in `col2` with following values `(1,2,3,4)`

I wrote the following query:

```
UPDATE table11
SET col2 = CASE col2 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 1
                 WHEN 1 THEN 2
                 when 1 THEN 3
                 WHEN 1 THEN 4
                 ELSE col2
                 END
                 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4);
```

But it is not working - output values of `col2` are not changing.

Comment: Your query replace each `1` in the col2 to the `1` in the first matched `WHEN` condition. Try to replace to the (5,6,7,8) and see - all your `1`s turns into `5`s.

Comment: @Kondybas yeah it replacing with first values ..how to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want to enumerate records in a table with the `id` (or `col1`) ascending order?

Comment: @Akina Yes enumerate the records with ascending order.

Comment: *with ascending order* There is **NO** ascending order! There exists ascending order **while sorting by** some field, fields combination or calculated expression. The best choice when each record is unique by sorting expression.

Comment: Why not `UPDATE table11 SET col2 = id ;` ?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ my replacement  values are `not be a id values` for understanding the problem i just using the `(1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign some values to the `col2` according to the `id` you have to create the auxiliary table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     5 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     7 |
| .. | ..... |
```

Then you have to `UPDATE` by `JOIN..ON` like that:

```
UPDATE table11  AS w
  JOIN auxtable AS z ON z.id = w.id
   SET w.col2 = z.value
;
```

It is crucial to have the index(id) for the auxiliary table. Otherwise query will fall into the filesort that can be VERY slow on big tables.

This is the universal solution for the mass updating. If you heed to update only few rows you can use the next query:

```
UPDATE table11 
   SET col2 = CASE
                 WHEN id=1 THEN 2
                 WHEN id=2 THEN 5
                 WHEN id=3 THEN 3
                 WHEN id=4 THEN 7
                 ELSE col2
              END
 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
;
```

As suggested by `ypercube` the clause `WHERE id IN (...)` is mandatory. If absent the query will drill through the whole table in search for the matching `id`s.